# Entity Framework 6 identical class conflict

Tags: database, entity-framework, class, model

Im my model I have an `Order` class and then I added a database context which has a table called `Order`. Beacuse of that I now have a conflict. I therefore tried to change the entity set name to `DbOrder`, but this did not help.

What do I need to change to get this to work without changing the class `Order` to another name?

Comment: Can you show an example of the conflict.

Comment: *I now have a conflict* -- It would be better to show an exact exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Change the namespaces so that the two `Order` classes can be distinguished from each other

```
namespace MyRoootNamespace.Models {
    public class Order {...}
}
//...
namespace MyRoootNamespace.Data {
    public class Order {...}
}
```

Comment: No. They already are in two namespaces, because they can't be in the same namespace. This is a known issue with EF type discovery.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Jumped the gun on this one.

Comment: Thought it over and they can be in the same namespace if the classes are partial. But again that shouldn't cause a conflict. I still agree with the know issue.

Comment: Partial classes are one class. OP is talking about two different classes.

Comment: Understood. I'm just saying it is possible that the two different classes can both be partial and in the same namespace. If i have `partial class A` and in the same project I add datacontext with a table named `A` in the same namespace then it is possible that the two classes may compile or cause the conflict.

Comment: I asked the OP to clarify with an example so that the above mention scenario can be ruled out.